# String interpolation in HiveQL

Tags: amazon-s3, hive, hiveql

I'm trying to create an external table that routes to an S3 bucket. I want to group all the tables by date, so the path will be something like `s3://<bucketname>/<date>/<table-name>`. My current function for creating it looks something like

```
concat('s3://<bucket-name>/', date_format(current_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'), '/<table-name>/');
```

I can run this in a `SELECT`query fine; however when I try to put it in my table creation statement, I get the following error:

```
set s3-path = concat('s3://<bucket-name>/', date_format(current_date,'yyyy-MM-dd'), '/<table-name>/');

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE users
(id STRING,
name STRING)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION ${hiveconf:s3-path};

> FAILED: ParseException line 7:9 mismatched input 'concat' expecting StringLiteral near 'LOCATION' in table location specification
```

Is there any way to do string interpolation or a function invocation in Hive in this context?

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this. [retrieve udf results in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825726/retrieve-udf-results-in-hive/41830114#41830114). Essentially, as workaround, you can create a script and call it from the terminal passing the parameter like a hive config.